# Duplicate elements in a list

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

I have a `list` in Python:

```
l = ['a', 'c', 'e', 'b']
```

I want to duplicate each element immediately next to the original.

```
ll = ['a', 'a', 'c', 'c', 'e', 'e', 'b', 'b']
```

The order of the elements should be preserved.

Comment: Related questions: [Repeating elements of a list n times](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24225072/7851470), [Best way to extend a list with itself N times](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46560385/7851470).

Comment: @Georgy this is the same as the repeating-n-times question. "There's no such thing as two", as they say. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_one_infinity_rule

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
>>> l = ['a', 'c', 'e', 'b']
>>> [x for pair in zip(l,l) for x in pair]
['a', 'a', 'c', 'c', 'e', 'e', 'b', 'b']
```

Or

```
>>> from itertools import repeat
>>> [x for item in l for x in repeat(item, 2)]
['a', 'a', 'c', 'c', 'e', 'e', 'b', 'b']
```

Comment: As a note, this won't work for arbitrary iterables that can be exhausted.

Comment: @Lattyware:  True, but it does work for the problem as described.

Comment: Indeed, it was just something to keep in mind in case someone tries to apply it in another situation.

Comment: @Lattyware:  Concern addressed in second version.

Comment: Yup, only problem I have there is the multi-loop list comp is a relatively inefficient way to flatten a list. In this case, not likely to matter, but it's also a little hard to read. That said, it's not wrong and other answers have already suggested `itertools.chain.from_iterable()`, so it's no big deal.

Answer (score 17):

This is old but I can't see the straightforward option here (IMO):

```
[ item for item in l for repetitions in range(2) ]
```

So for the specific case:

```
>>> l = ['a', 'c', 'e', 'b']
l = ['a', 'c', 'e', 'b']
>>> [ i for i in l for r in range(2) ]
[ i for i in l for r in range(2) ]
['a', 'a', 'c', 'c', 'e', 'e', 'b', 'b']
>>>
```

And generalizing:

```
[ item for item in l for _ in range(r) ]
```

Where r is the quantity of repetitions you want.

So this has a O(n.r) space and time complexity, is short, with no dependencies and also idiomatic.

Comment: Works in Python 3 as well, exactly what I was looking for :)

Answer (score 7):

```
import itertools

ll = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable((e, e) for e in l))
```

At work:

```
>>> import itertools
>>> l = ['a', 'c', 'e', 'b']
>>> ll = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable((e, e) for e in l))
>>> ll
['a', 'a', 'c', 'c', 'e', 'e', 'b', 'b']
```

As Lattyware pointed out, in case you want more than just double the element:

```
from itertools import chain, repeat

ll = list(chain.from_iterable(repeat(e, 2) for e in l))
```

Comment: To make this a little more flexible `itertools.repeat()` might be a better option.

Comment: I think you wanted `chain.from_iterable`

Comment: I'm sorry, but I had to edit to get rid of that space between `chain` and it's argument list. Also, fixed by using `chain.from_iterable()` as mgilson suggested. I also added spaces between arguments as appropriate, and changed `_` - which is usually used to signify a throw away value.

Comment: @Lattyware, it's OK. I can't do anything about the spaces (coding standards at my job, yeesh. Hard to kick the habbit). But you just beat me to the `from_iterable`

Comment: @StoryTeller Really? That sucks. It's directly against what PEP-8 recommends, and I (personally) think it's ugly as hell.

Comment: @Lattyware, I code in C++ for a living and python for fun. So it's even worse :)
The spaces after the commas are a typo, though.

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
for i in l:
    ll.append(i)
    ll.append(i)
```

[Demo](http://ideone.com/fFYtxt)

It will just do your work but it's not an optimized way of doing this.

use the ans. posted by @Steven Rumbalski

Comment: This is a relatively inefficient way of doing this.

Comment: @Lattyware Agree but this Ques. doesn't deserve more than this.it is not mentioned that it require an optimized solution.it just want a solution.

Comment: That's a crazy way to look at it. The better answers are generally similar amounts of code to this, and it's always worth doing things the best way possible where it doesn't take extra effort to do so.

Comment: Ok @Lattyware next time i will remember this. but what can i do now.(The solution is already given and tesla itself know the ans.)

Comment: Where did I say that you needed to do anything about it? It's a valid solution to the answer, I'm just commented that it was relatively inefficient, and didn't upvote because it isn't a particularly useful solution.

Comment: @Lattyware Oh! thanks for pointing this. next time i will take care of this. :)

Comment: @Arpit this man deserves a golden medal. It works without any complications and that's all it matters.

Comment: @GarethLatty it is a useful solution for me even during 2020

Comment: @GarethLatty and I'm upvoting this

Answer (score 2):

Here's a pretty easy way:

```
sum(zip(l, l), tuple())
```

It duplicates each item, and adds them to a tuple. If you don't want a tuple (as I suspect), you can call `list` on the the tuple:

```
list(sum(zip(l, l), tuple()))
```

---

A few other versions (that yield lists):

```
list(sum(zip(l, l), ()))

sum([list(i) for i in zip(l, l)], [])

sum(map(list, zip(l, l)), [])
```

Comment: This works, but it takes quadratic time. It's a really bad option.

Answer (score 1):

Pandas gives a method for duplicated elements:

```
import pandas as pd
l = pd.Series([2, 1, 3, 1])
print(l.duplicated())
>>>0    False
   1    False
   2    False
   3     True
   dtype: bool

print('Has list duplicated ? :', any(l.duplicated()))
>>>Has list duplicated ? : True
```