# Repeat list n times, sorted by original order

Tags: python

I cannot find a solution to the following problem
I have a list of strings, say

```
base_list = ['d', 'ssa', 'aaa', 'bb']
```

and I want to repeat this list `n` times but I need to keep the order of the original list. For example with `n=2` the result should be:

```
final_list =  ['d', 'd', 'ssa', 'ssa', 'aaa', 'aaa', 'bb', 'bb']
```

EDIT: Not sure if I should mark this question as duplicate or not, since it is in my opinion more generic than the possible duplicate [Duplicate element in python list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14878538)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14878538/duplicate-element-in-python-list

Comment: That solves it, despite that the original question asked for duplicates and not the case where `n` is arbitrary. Probably why I have not found the question in first place.

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> base_list = ['d', 'ssa', 'aaa', 'bb']
>>> n = 2
>>> [i for i in base_list for _ in xrange(n)]
['d', 'd', 'ssa', 'ssa', 'aaa', 'aaa', 'bb', 'bb']
```

Inside list comprehension you iterate through range with `n` length (inside loop) and through original list with outer one.

Answer (score 0):

The following should do what you're looking for

```
>>> base_list = ['d', 'ssa', 'aaa', 'bb']
>>> final_list = []
>>> n = 10
>>> for item in base_list:
...     for i in range(n):
...             final_list.append(item)
... 
>>> final_list
['d', 'd', 'd', 'd', 'd', 'd', 'd', 'd', 'd', 'd', 'ssa', 'ssa', 'ssa', 'ssa', 'ssa', 'ssa', 'ssa', 'ssa', 'ssa', 'ssa', 'aaa', 'aaa', 'aaa', 'aaa', 'aaa', 'aaa', 'aaa', 'aaa', 'aaa', 'aaa', 'bb', 'bb', 'bb', 'bb', 'bb', 'bb', 'bb', 'bb', 'bb', 'bb']
```

Answer (score 0):

It is already [explained here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14878538/duplicate-element-in-python-list)

Applied to your code:

```
>>> base_list = ['d', 'ssa', 'aaa', 'bb']
>>> from itertools import repeat
>>> final_list = [x for item in base_list for x in repeat(item, 2)]
>>> final_list
['d', 'd', 'ssa', 'ssa', 'aaa', 'aaa', 'bb', 'bb']
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess one answer from the tagged question (where n=2) also applies to the more generic case:

```
from itertools import chain, repeat

final_list = list(chain.from_iterable(repeat(item, n) for item in base_list))
```

Comment: This is good one, but for small lists its kinda overkill.

Answer (score 0):

My first thought was to zip it with itself, then flatten:

```
import itertools
base_list = ['d', 'ssa', 'aaa', 'bb']
n = 2
list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(zip(*[base_list] * n)))
```

Comment: This probably runs fastest, without any imports:

    Line 1: `n = 2`    
    Line 2: `list(sum(zip(*[base_list] * n), ()))`

Comment: `sum` is quadratic rather than linear though.