# Duplicate elements in list

Tags: python

I have a list of string `s = ['a', 'b', 'c']`

I want to to get `s = ['a','a','a','b','b','b','c','c','c']`

I've tried vstack, then reshape but got `s = ['a', 'b', 'c','a', 'b', 'c','a', 'b', 'c']`

Is there any way to do that other than for loop?

here is the code:

```
a = ["a","b","c"]
a = np.array(a)
b = np.vstack((a,a,a))
b.reshape(-1)
```

> array(['a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'c'], dtype='<U1')

Comment: You can consider [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14878538/duplicate-element-in-python-list)

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> orig = ['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> n = 3
>>> s = sum(map(lambda x:[x]*n, orig), [])
>>> s
['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'c']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
s = ['a', 'b', 'c']
print ([i for i in s for _ in range(3)])
```

output:

```
['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'c']
```