# How to duplicate elements in a nested list?

Tags: python, python-itertools, nested-lists

I have a nested list that looks like this:

```
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
```

I want to duplicate each element in each inner list by 3 and place them side to side as such:

```
[[1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3], [4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6], [7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9]]
```

This is my current solution:

```
from itertools import repeat

x2 = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]

ls = []
for i in x2:
    ls.append([x for item in i for x in repeat(item, 3)])
ls
>>> [[1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3],
 [5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7],
 [9, 9, 9, 10, 10, 10, 11, 11, 11],
 [4, 4, 4, 8, 8, 8, 3, 3, 3]]
```

Is there any way to make it faster?

Comment: If you make use of lambda x function, there is a way to do it using np.repeat()! First use 'f = lambda x:np.repeat(x2,3)'. Then use 'np.apply_along_axis(f,1,x)' and you will get the same answer.

Comment: If your code doesn't have any problems and you are looking for improvements; Code Review is the right place to ask not Stack Overflow.

Comment: Oh ok sorry this is my first time submitting a question, thank you for your input, I will do so next time.

Comment: Thanks, seems to work too :)

Comment: This can be done with a one-liner, list-comprehension `dupes = [[val for val in sublist for i in range(3)] for sublist in x2]`. Not sure if it's faster though.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one solution:

```
ls=[sum([[i]*3 for i in k], []) for k in x2]

>>>print(ls)
[[1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3], [4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6], [7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9]]
```

Answer (score 1):

As you asked for *faster*, here are some comparisons between the different possible ways presented here and other places.

- I used your method using `repeat` and added a list-comp version of it just to match the others.
- I used [@IoaTzimas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8228558/ioatzimas) [version using `sum`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65234505/6045800).
- I used the version using `zip` of [@Steven Rumbalski](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1322401/steven-rumbalski) from [Duplicate elements in a list](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14878621/6045800)
- I used the "pure" list-comp solution by [@Wololo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4010950/wololo) [from the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65234232/how-to-duplicate-elements-in-a-nested-list-python#comment115327666_65234232).

The results (on my machine) are (ordered ascending):

```
using_zip         5.630
using_repeat_comp 5.818
using_sum         5.905
using_repeat      6.421
using_pure        6.878
```

Surprisingly (to me), the `zip` solution is actually fastest, and the list-comp version of your `repeat` solution second. I would assume that the "pure" list-comp will be fastest but it was actually the worst. I guess [TIL](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/til#:%7E:text=TIL%20in%20English-,TIL,recorded%20using%20the%20same%20piano.)...

---

There is another result (proposed by [@Henry Tjhia](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14185713/henry-tjhia)):

```
using_sort        3.219
```

Significantly better as you can see, but I put it separately as it relies heavily on the above specific example. So if you want to duplicate a list of ascending numbers that would be your best choice.

---

The code to produce them is:

```py
import timeit
from itertools import repeat

x2 = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]

def using_repeat():
    ls = []
    for i in x2:
        ls.append([x for item in i for x in repeat(item, 3)])
    return ls

def using_repeat_comp():
    return [[x for item in i for x in repeat(item, 3)] for i in x2]

def using_zip():
    return [[x for triple in zip(l, l, l) for x in triple] for l in x2]

def using_sum():
    return [sum([[i]*3 for i in k], []) for k in x2]

def using_pure():
    return [[val for val in sublist for _ in range(3)] for sublist in x2]

def using_sort():
    return [sorted(sub[:]*3) for sub in x2]

for func in [using_repeat, using_repeat_comp, using_zip, using_sum, using_pure, using_sort]:
    print(func.__name__, timeit.timeit(f"{func.__name__}()", f"from __main__ import {func.__name__}"))
```

Comment: Ah, you beat me to it: I was just finishing my `timeit` testing of the same approaches, +1!. It intrigues me that `zip` is fastest.. it is also the "least" expandable approach, say if the user suddenly wants 4 copies and not 3..

Comment: @Wololo agree. It surprised me as well. My natural choice would be your list-comp which surprisingly as well is actually the slowest!

Comment: My bad, I just noticed that. In my testing with your code, the ```sum``` way always consistently outperforms the ```zip``` and others.

Comment: @Tomerikoo That would be great. But since ordering is important, we can forget it :).

Comment: @HenryTjhia, no don't forget it. When it comes to optimization, specific problems may often need specific solutions, and a performance boost like that is not to be trifled with. This was an eye-opener for me, and a valuable lesson.