# Repeat every element in list x times

Tags: python, list

I have got 2 lists:
`A=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]` and `B=[3, 2, 5, 2, 4]` and would like to repeat every `i`th element of `A` `B[i]` times, so for given lists it would be:

`repA = [ 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4]` so now we have three `0`, two `1`, five `2` and so on. I found that [duplicating solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14878538/duplicate-elements-in-a-list) but have no idea how to do it for different times (writen in `B` list)

Their code is like `[ item for item in list for _ in range(repetition) ]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I found that duplicating solution but have no idea how to do it for different times (writen in B list)

Well, how does the existing code determine the number of repetitions? From the constant value `repetition`, right? So, what you need is to replace that with a corresponding element of `B` for each of the elements from `A` being repeated, yeah? So, the problem boils down to [iterating over those two lists in parallel](/questions/1663807/how-to-iterate-through-two-lists-in-parallel).

So, given

```
A = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
B = [3, 2, 5, 2, 4]
```

We want: the `a` element, `for` each of the `a, b` pairs that we get by `zip`ping together `A` and `B` (iterating over them in parallel), repeated `b` times.

I structured that description to match the corresponding list comprehension:

```
[a for a, b in zip(A, B) for _ in range(b)]
```

which we can mechanically translate into the corresponding `for` loops:

```
result = []
for a, b in zip(A, B):
    for _ in range(b):
        result.append(a)
```

Translating from a comprehension into procedural code, the `for` (and `if`, where applicable) clauses [appear in the same order, and the thing being appended moves from the front into the innermost block](https://treyhunner.com/2015/12/python-list-comprehensions-now-in-color/).

Answer (score 1):

You just need to use `zip` to pair items with counts, then use the count to determine how many times to repeat the item. It ends up *very* similar to the example code you provided.

```
[item for item, count in zip(A, B) for _ in range(count)]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to do this in a lazily-evaluated, functional way, you can use a couple tools from [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html) to do this:

```
from itertools import repeat, starmap, chain

A = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
B = [3, 2, 5, 2, 4]

c = chain.from_iterable(starmap(repeat, zip(A, B)))

# evaluate
print(list(c))
# [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4]
```

This doesn't buy you much for a small list, but can be useful if you are starting with large input or the number of repetitions is large since you never need to create the entire list in memory if you don't want to.

The code above maps the input from the two lists to [repeat()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.repeat()), and then uses [chain.from_iterable()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable) to flatten the output to a single iterator.

Comment: You *could* do that, but it's a lot more complex than just replacing the `[]` of a list comprehension with `()` to get a generator expression.

Comment: I suppose it's a matter of style and opinion. I find the above more readable and the intention more obvious. Of course, YMMV.

Comment: Also, @KarlKnechtel, using itertools is *significantly* faster when either A or B are large. I suspect `range()` is the bottleneck.

Comment: Yes, over 5 times as fast in my testing. Good to know. I find it difficult to believe that the creation of the `range` objects itself is the bottleneck, since not that many of them are created and they're lazily evaluated. However, iterating over them - in particular, getting values from the range that are then thrown away to `_` - might be a problem.

Comment: Further testing results: `chain.from_iterable` and `repeat` *both* need to be used to get a performant result; if either is replaced using the equivalent generator-expression mechanics, the performance is negligibly improved (or even made worse). However, `starmap` is irrelevant to the performance boost. Thus `chain.from_iterable(repeat(a, b) for a, b in zip(A, B))` works almost as well.

Comment: Odd that neither of you used `chain.from_iterable(map(repeat, A, B))` ... @KarlKnechtel

Comment: It's a good point @KellyBundy. Honestly, I always forget you can use `map()` that way. Maybe 2024 me will make a point to work that into practice.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps try something like this:

```py
A=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
B=[3, 2, 5, 2, 4]

res = []
for num, mult in zip(A, B):
    res.extend([num]*mult)

print(res)
```

What happens when we zip `A` and `B` and unpack it into `num` and `mult`, it says pair the first `num` in `A` with the furst `mult` in `B`. Same for the second, third and so on.

Then `[num]*mult` returns say `[3]*5 = [3,3,3,3,3]`.

And when `.extend` is used for a list it simply extends the list by the argument.

`res = [0, 0, 0]` so `res.extend([3,3,3,3,3])` gives us `res = [0,0,0,3,3,3,3,3]`.