# How to make a 1-hour gif using Python?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, gif, animated-gif

I want to make an 1 hour - long gif which will consist of 60 frames.

I already have built a gif_making function using PIL:

```
      sortedFiles = sorted(glob.glob('*.png'),key=os.path.getmtime)
      sortedFilesBackwards = sorted(glob.glob('*.png'),key=os.path.getmtime, reverse= True)

      full = [] + sortedFiles[:-1] + sortedFilesBackwards[:-1]
      frames = [Image.open(image) for image in full]
      
      frame_one = frames[0]
      frame_one.save(f"{units}{fileName}.gif", format="GIF", append_images=frames,
                  save_all=True, duration=12000, loop=0)
```

However, when I set the duration = 360 000 (milliseconds = 1 hour), I receive the following error:

> struct.error: ushort format requires 0 <= number <= (32767 *2 +1)

I work on macOS.

P.S : I think it has something to do with the maximum amount of data within a struct ?

Answer (score 1):

The duration is how long to display each frame for in milliseconds, so you need to set it to 1,000 for each frame to be displayed for a second.

Or set it to 30,000 for each frame to be displayed for 30 seconds and double up your frames.

Comment: still, even if I set the duration = 60.000 (60 seconds), I still get the error

Comment: That's why I suggested 30,000... because it is less than 32,768.

Comment: that did work. 

As a conclusion: there is a duration limit of 32 seconds per image ?

Comment: @NiceBro so instead of 60 frames you will have 120, where the odd frames are exact duplicates of the preceding even one.

Comment: @NiceBro the limit probably comes from the GIF format itself.  It's the largest value you can put into a signed 16-bit field.

Comment: in that case, I would have to rewrite the sorting and create duplicates

Comment: Duplicate list like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/14878621/2836621

Answer (score 0):

Set FPS value when you saving your GIF
For example:

```
ani.save('animation.gif', fps=3)
```

The value you set will lengthen or shorten your gif

Comment: That doesn't work. 

I want to 1 frame per Minute.

Comment: What if you set fps to fps = 1/60?

Comment: It didn't work.